# Lucidity and pain reduction link

Tags: medications, pain

I am a layman, so this is no doubt an overly broad and probably dumb question, but if someone will humor me and attempt to answer, I would greatly appreciate it. Why is it that studies tend to show a negative correlation between medications (particularly for pain, but almost regardless of the drug's purpose) and cognitive functioning? Do we know whether it is possible to reduce pain without affecting - or perhaps enhancing - logical reasoning?

Comment: Do you have links to the studies in the question?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. Without linking to the studies you mentioned as @JMP has asked, the question is unclear. As the request has not been followed, I have voted to put this question on hold. [From Review](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/19236)